# create an array like structure if doesn't exists in a file and add content to it in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I need to check if an array exists in a file and create it if doesn't exists and add content to it as explained below:

a.txt:

```
fs.m = [
 abc,
]
```

Suppose I need to add ‘xyz’ to the array like this:

```
fs.m = [
 xyz,
 abc,
]
```

If array doesn’t exists then after creating new array and adding ‘xyz’ to it would look like:

```
fs.m = [
 xyz,
]
```

bash script I am using to solve it:
add_array_text.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

if grep -A1 -qE '^fs.m *= *\[' a.txt; then
    echo -e "xyz," >> a.txt
else
    echo -e 'fs.m = [' >> a.txt
    echo -e "xyz," >> a.txt
    echo -e "]" >> a.txt
fi
```

After execuing `add_array_text.sh`, a.txt:

```
fs.m = [
 abc,
]
xyz
```

If array exists, above script add content outside of array, at the end of file which is wrong.

With `A1` I tried to get the file context after the match but not able to save it and use it.

Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: So if the first array exists, add `xyz,` after the first line and what should happen if there are no arrays or if the second array exists already?

Comment: Also when you say _array_ you should define which language that _array_ is since it is definitely not bash nor shell.

Comment: You said `I need to a add a string to the array like this if array exists` but you didn't say what should happen if the "array" doesn't exist. [edit] your question to state that requirement and show associated expected output.

Comment: @Jetchisel that’s irrelevant. Array need not to match any language requirement. It could be new thing I have developing. Problem here is related to pattern matching and adding text.

Comment: please update the question with the results of running the script against the file when the array does exist; I'm *guessing* it appends `xyz` at the end of the file ... which is exactly what the script says to do: `echo -e "xyz" >> a.txt`

Comment: "*Problem here is related to pattern matching*". Yes, focus on getting the `grep` command to work, just on the cmd-line, without any extra `bash` logic around it. Turn off the `q` flag so you can see what is being output, and then adjust other arguments to `grep` until you get the ouput you need. THEN you can turn on `-q` again, Good luck.

Comment: @Jeetu, if the Array is irrelevant then why mention it at the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I made it working with below script `add_array_text.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! grep -q '^fs.m[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\[' a.txt; then
    echo 'fs.m = [' >> a.txt
    echo "xyz," >> a.txt
    echo "]" >> a.txt
else
    sed -i 's/\(^fs.m[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*\[\)/\1'"\nxyz,"'/' a.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If an array exists, you can do following (assuming file is not too large)

```
    new_element='xyz'
    cat a.txt | while read line; do
        echo $line >> b.txt
        if [[ $line =~ 'fs.m = [' ]]; then
            echo ${new_element}, >> b.txt
        fi
    done
    mv a.txt a_old.txt
    mv b.txt a.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the answer though it doesn't solve both if and else cases in the question. also it add more complexity. I implemented a simpler one and posted here.